# Xcode 9 iOS 11 BoringSSL SSL_ERROR_ZERO_RETURN

Tags: ios, xcode, boringssl

I have a simple program HelloWorld running on iOS. The same code has been running fine for a long time. Recently, I notice that I get the below BoringSSL error when the program runs on my ipad connected to Xcode 9 on my Macbook. I don't see this error when I run the program in simulator. The iOS is 11.2. Xcode is 9.2.

My code has no reference to BoringSSL. However, it does use NSMutableURLRequest to make https call to a server. The call works fine and everything seems to work fine except the BoringSSL messages.

Is there a way the I can debug why the message comes up? HellowWorld[466:85961], what do those 2 numbers mean?

What does the message mean and how to avoid it?

```
2017-12-13 15:41:13.486047-0500 HellowWorld[466:85961] [BoringSSL] Function boringssl_session_errorlog: line 2871 [boringssl_session_read] SSL_ERROR_ZERO_RETURN(6): operation failed because the connection was cleanly shut down with a close_notify alert
2017-12-13 15:41:13.486363-0500 HellowWorld[466:85961] [BoringSSL] Function boringssl_session_errorlog: line 2871 [boringssl_session_read] SSL_ERROR_ZERO_RETURN(6): operation failed because the connection was cleanly shut down with a close_notify alert
```

[image: Screenshot added]

Comment: I have the same issue, did not find a solution yet, I'm using Alamofire with a network request and the same error/warning is showing

Comment: A similar question here on SO listed this as a possible explanation: https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/issues/14418#issuecomment-308850249

Comment: Also have the same issue

Comment: I have the same issue

Comment: Same for me using the Alamofire AFNetworking api. It happens to me when my rest-api takes time to respond. Could it be an Alamo fire time out on slow server response?

Comment: @Alex: same issue for me, but I don't use Alamofire, I simply use my own Swift networking code and a PHP backend. This happens with any kind of request, even if there's no time involved (if I only get "Hello" from the server, it happens anyway). In my case, the app crashes IF there's a contemporary Internet issue (eg. connection error due to broadband issues)

Comment: I run into this problem too no idea why it happens. My API calls and all the HTTP stuff works as expected but this error gets printed sometimes.

Comment: From openssl documentation https://www.openssl.org/docs/manmaster/man3/SSL_get_error.html:

"SSL_ERROR_ZERO_RETURN: 
The TLS/SSL connection has been closed. If the protocol version is SSL 3.0 or higher, this result code is returned only if a closure alert has occurred in the protocol, i.e. if the connection has been closed cleanly. Note that in this case SSL_ERROR_ZERO_RETURN does not necessarily indicate that the underlying transport has been closed."

Comment: I found that the issue in my case was a problem with headers, on the api side there where empty spaces above or below <?php ?> tags and the headers weren't set correctly at the correct places where needed.

Comment: Did you find a solution please?

Comment: same issue here. did you find the reason ?

Comment: No one replied about the 2 numbers: they are typically the process id and thread id or some connection identifier. So they will change at each run. It just allows to group error related error messages together.

Answer (score 21):

> Is there a way the I can debug why the message comes up?

**Yes**, *there is*, and I'm a bit surprised it hadn't been mentioned yet.

`CFNetwork` handles the core of `Foundation`’s networking classes — It also has the (often overlooked) capability of detailed logging via the **`CFNETWORK_DIAGNOSTICS`** environment variable.

**Programmatically enabling `CFNetwork` diagnostic logging**:

```
setenv("CFNETWORK_DIAGNOSTICS", "3", 1);
```

It should be set to an integer value from 0 to 3, where 0 is off and higher numbers give progressively more logging. During normal development you can set this environment variable via Xcode’s scheme editor. When the app is run from Xcode, the `CFNetwork` log entries will appear in the debug console area (if not visible, choose `View` > `Debug Area` > `Show Debug Area`).

The environment variable should be placed right at the beginning of the app’s launch sequence. Normally putting this at the start of main is sufficient, but if you have C++ static initialisers that use `CFNetwork` you’ll have to put it before those.

> Note: In Swift this code would go in `main.swift`. By default Swift apps
>   don’t have a `main.swift`; “The Swift Programming Language” explains how
>   to add one.
>   <sub>*Also note, in Swift remove the semi-colon at the end of the `setenv`.</sub>

Setting the environment variable above should definitely help in determining where the issue is, or at the very least give you a starting point to begin diagnosing a somewhat vague error message.

↳ [CFNetwork Diagnostic Logging](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/qa/qa1887/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40015177-CH1-SECLOGGINGWITHOUTXCODE)

Comment: Actually tried ´setenv("CFNETWORK_DIAGNOSTICS", "3", 1);´ and it bricked my iPhone 6+. So a word of warning: only set this through Xcode scheme editor....... And start with a gentle value such as "1".

Answer (score 0):

I managed to fix the issue by adding the "App Transport Security Settings" key to the info.plist. Make sure that "Allow Arbitrary Loads" is set to "Yes".

Comment: The "Allow Arbitary Loads" property is set to "Yes". But I'm still getting these errors. For some messed up reason, when my app tries to upload data to our server which is using an HTTPS address, it fails, and any subsequent nagivation or pull-to-refresh actions will freeze the app. Any ideas?

Comment: Perhaps if I whitelist my server address (https://my-server.com) in the plist file, it would work then .. ?

Answer (score 0):

For those of you for whom the above methods did not work, this is what the problem was in my case:

I was sending a `GET` request with a JSON *request body* using [Alamofire](https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire). I changed it to a `GET` request that contains the parameters as query parameters in the URL instead (along the lines of `GET https://your-api.com/v1/request?param=value`). Then it worked flawlessly.

Answer (score -1):

I got a similar message when trying to use NSLog to post a very long list as it would post the list for a long time in the debug console then it so list part of the list followed by a few `...` to show there was more that was not printed in the console, I fixed this (using OBJ-C) and adding this #define to my VC.m

```
#define NSLog(FORMAT, ...) printf("%s\n", [[NSString stringWithFormat:FORMAT, ##__VA_ARGS__] UTF8String]);
```

perhaps you can use something similar to your swift project.